# Failed to Get Array OpenStreetMap API Json

Tags: php, json, api

I'm new to programming.

I am trying to get coordinate location from JSON data. Here my script:

```
$jsonurl = "http://photon.komoot.de/api/?q=kemang+timur+jakarta&limit=1";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
$json_output = json_decode($json, true);

echo $json_output['features'][0]['type']['geometry']['coordinates'];
```

But, it failed. I just get error messages.

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'geometry' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mios\open\lokasi.php on line 12 Warning: Illegal string offset 'coordinates' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mios\open\lokasi.php on line 12 F

Here if i print JSON data

```
Array ( [features] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [geometry] => Array ( [coordinates] => Array ( [0] => 106.8230188 [1] => -6.2631289 ) [type] => Point ) [type] => Feature [properties] => Array ( [osm_id] => 31779962 [osm_type] => W [extent] => Array ( [0] => 106.8220505 [1] => -6.2624677 [2] => 106.823754 [3] => -6.263854 ) [country] => Indonesia [osm_key] => highway [city] => Jakarta Special Capital Region [osm_value] => residential [postcode] => 12730 [name] => Jalan Kemang Timur VI ) ) ) [type] => FeatureCollection )
```

Comment: post you stack trace of error or explain what error you get in question section.

Comment: @parladneupane here the error meaasage: Warning: Illegal string offset 'geometry' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mios\open\lokasi.php on line 12

Warning: Illegal string offset 'coordinates' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mios\open\lokasi.php on line 12
F

Comment: For take the coordinate you need to do echo $json_output['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'][0 or 1 ]

Comment: @ErDiablo Thanks, it works!